# Chrome extension messaging error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension where when the extension first starts (browser is started/extension is updated) a window is opened with a html file containing a form asking for a master password. When this master password does not match a certain string, a message is sent through `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. A message is also sent the same way when the modal window is closed through the `chrome.windows.onRemoved` listener.

Here is my service worker:

```js
/// <reference types="chrome-types"/>

(async () => {
    console.log('Extension started. Modal opened...');

  const window = await chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL("html/index.html"),
    type: "popup",
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
  });

  chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener((windowId) => {
    if (windowId === window?.id) chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ monitoringEnabled: true, reason: 'tab closed' }).catch(console.log);
  });

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    if (Object.hasOwn(message, 'monitoringEnabled')) {
        console.log(`Monitoring ${message.monitoringEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}. ${message.reason ? `Reason: ${message.reason}` : ''}`)

        chrome.storage.local.set({ monitoringEnabled: message.monitoringEnabled });

        if (window?.id) chrome.windows.remove(window.id);
    }

    return true;
  });
})();
```

The html file just has a form with a button which when clicked triggers a script:

```js
const MASTER_PASSWORD = 'some_thing_here';

document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const password = document.getElementById('master-password-text-field').value;

    if (password !== MASTER_PASSWORD) return chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ monitoringEnabled: true, reason: 'invalid password' })
    
    return chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ monitoringEnabled: false })
})
```

These are some logs:
[image]

The first error is when the modal tab is closed, notice that nothing happens after this (i.e  onMessage listener is not triggered). However, in the second case, when a message is sent from the modal script, the onMessage listener is triggered, but the connection error still appears after the code in the listener has processed.

Not sure why this happens. I have checked multiple other threads on the same topic but none of them seem to help me. If you have a better idea on what I can do to achieve what I want right now, please suggest.

Comment: I think the service worker cannot call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

Comment: Hmm yes, that seems to be the case. I will have to work without sending a message when a tab is closed then.

Comment: The error however still occurs in the first case where a message goes through from the modal script.

Comment: You are registering onMessage asynchronously which means it won't wake up the worker after the worker is auto-terminated. More info: [Why must MV3 chrome extensions(using service workers) "register listeners in the first turn of the event loop"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516519)

Comment: The issue still occurs when registering onMessage synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I'm sending a message to the service worker in the server worker itself. I've re-wrote my code by just making a function which is called when the `windows.onRemoved` event is triggered and also when a message is sent from the modal tab. The seems to have fixed my issue. This is my service worker code for reference:

```js
/// <reference types="chrome-types"/>

console.log('Extension started. Modal opened...');

let windowId: number | null = null;

chrome.windows
    .create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL('html/index.html'),
        type: 'popup',
        width: 400,
        height: 600
    })
    .then((created) => (windowId = created?.id ?? null));

chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener((id) => {
    if (id === windowId) enableMonitoring('window closed')

});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    if (message.monitoringEnabled) {
        enableMonitoring(message.reason);
    }

    return undefined
})

function enableMonitoring(reason: any) {
    console.log('monitoring enabled', reason);
}
```