# chome.alarms.onAlarm not triggered when a listener is in an async function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, listener, alarm

It's about Chrome extensions and MV3.

I know Chrome recommends adding listeners at the top level of your service worker in MV3, but I have an existing code that doesn't do that and it works...sometimes. In general the logic is described here: [Why must MV3 Chrome extensions (using Service Workers) "register listeners in the first turn of the event loop"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74515794/why-must-mv3-chrome-extensions-using-service-workers-register-listeners-in-th) but there are little quirks I'd like to understand.

A simplified version of the service worker with a bug:

```js
(async () => {
  log("Starting SW...");
  await chrome.alarms.clear("my-alarm");

  // Clear if exists
  log("Alarms cleaned up");
  chrome.alarms.getAll((alarms) => {
    log("Cleaned?", alarms);
  });

  // Set up an alarm
  await chrome.alarms.create("my-alarm", {
    periodInMinutes: 1,
  });
  log("Alarm created");
  chrome.alarms.getAll((alarms) => {
    log("Created?", alarms);
  });

  // Add a listener
  chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
    log("Our listener fired");
    if (alarm.name === "my-alarm") {
      log("Omg my alarm has been triggered");
    }
  });
  log("Listener added. Finishing.");
})();

// this is a helper fn that helps me debugging SW when they sleep
// the goal is to push logs to my local server and see them in the terminal
// so that I don't interfere with SW life cycle
function log(...data) {
  console.log(...data);
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/?t=${JSON.stringify(data)}`).catch((e) => {});
}
```

Node server file:

```js
// don't judge me ;) 

const http = require("http");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  let content;

  try {
    content = decodeURIComponent(req.url);
  } catch (e) {
    content = req.url;
  }

  console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString(), "|", content);
  
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Hello, World!\n");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

When you upload an extension with such a worker file, it goes to sleep after a few seconds and then after a minute or so it wakes up but doesn't handle the alarm event at all. So it's probably because the event is gone after so many async/await statements and Chrome can't dispatch it correctly...

But what's more interesting, is that if you add a dummy listener at the top of the service worker, top level:

```js
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
  log("Top level listener fired for", alarm.name);
});

// rest of the file
```

It starts working! Suddenly alarm event is picked up by Chrome and delivered to all listeners, including the original one, deep in the async code.

So my question is - can I just add a dummy catch-all listener at the top of my entry point file and expect Chrome to properly deliver all alarm events from now on? Is there some sort of queue that handles events and delivers them to listeners added later if at least ONE listener is added at the top level?

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, but that's not the exact question here. I'm asking why my code starts working and delivers events to all, even async, listeners, when at least one listener is registered in the global scope. Not, that the async listener wakes up the worker, it just doesn't pick up the event.

Comment: I've tested it now and indeed the event is delivered to the belatedly registered listener, which is probably a bug in Chrome. I'll investigate it later today...